# elf objcopy --extract-symbol produce an output with a lot of zeros

Tags: c, arm, elf, objdump, cortex-m

I'm working on arm cortex-m4 processor and I want to extract all symbols needed for relocation from an elf. 
I found this realy usefull option --extract-symbols. So using this command:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy --extract-symbol sourceElf.elf destinationElf.elf
```

I'm able to compress a lot the original elf removing all sections that I don't care.

Analyzing the elf in output (destinationElf.elf) only three sections are not empty and these are the sections that I need to relocate code:

```
.shstrtab         
.symtab           
.strtab
```

The other sections are empty, but the elf has a lot of padding with 0s. 
This is due to section that are empty but they have an offset from the start of the elf?

Is this offset need to relocate? Is there a way to remove all the zero padding to have smaller elf in size?

Thank you

Comment: if size matters you can try formats other than elf...did those produce smaller files?

Comment: You mean like a .bin?

Comment: arm-none-eabi-objcopy --info  binary is one of those yes.  this is a microcontroller so the files are already pretty small, not sure why you need to squeeze a little bit more out.

Comment: I assume you have already exhausted the removal of compile and linker options that added (some of) those things in the first place?  if you dont add them then you dont need to try to remove them

Comment: just going to ihex and back to elf will remove all symbols, yes?